# Azure search services filter criteria not allowing special characters

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I want to filter data for special characters (-, ~, /) in Azure search services.
But it's not allowing, parsing error: `Failed to parse query string.`

Query: `$filter=search.ismatchscoring('~', 'name', 'any', 'full)`

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lucene Syntax you need to escape the special characters with a `\`
Try below

```
$filter=search.ismatchscoring('\~', 'Description', 'full', 'any')
```

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#escaping-special-characters